# Google Maps API Geocode Postal Code and set Country code?

Tags: api, google-maps

I'm using this API call to Google Maps to get the latitude and longitude of a postal code

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2340&sensor=false

The postal code is in Australia. This API call returns locations all around the world with partial matching postal codes in the address.

Is there a parameter I can use to set the country to Australia?

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The correct way to do this is not via region biasing but rather using [component filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#component-filtering):

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json
    ?components=country:AU|postal_code:2340
    &sensor=false
```

Some demonstrations:

- [2340](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:AU%7Cpostal_code:2340&sensor=false)
- [93274](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:AU%7Cpostal_code:93274&sensor=false)

Please note that if you use the components parameter, you don't need to specify the address parameter.

Comment: Why doesn't it work with a Queensland postcode? http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:AU|postal_code:4072&sensor=false

Comment: Thanks! just add the parameter ?components=country:ES and works perfectly for Spain

Comment: this endpoint now require a TOKEN to work

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says that [Region Biasing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#RegionCodes) is based on [CcTLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CcTLD), which would make Australia au (haven't tried it myself).

Although it also states this:

> Note that biasing only prefers results for a specific domain; if more relevant results exist outside of this domain, they may be included.

Comment: I found that `?address=2340,au&sensor=false` returns only results from Australia is that valid though?

Comment: Yes @Anagio thats correct, placing a ",usa" would result in displaying only results in the United States, however that only means its not going to look in any other country, it doesnt mean its gonna give you a correct result, for example if i put 93274,au it gives me some random town in Australia, but not the town in Australia for that Zip code... Whatever the reason, if your targeting a specific country, its best to go ahead and use what your suggesting. I know its been awhile for a response on this but i just happened to stumble upon it.

Comment: To add to Aaron's answer - the query above is ambiguous between an address in Australia with a STREET NUMBER of 2340 and a suburb with a POSTCODE of 2340. Goggle appears to search street numbers first which means that the probability of getting back a town in WoopWoop is proportional to the numeric value of the postcode. Less likely in QLD (postcodes 4000 plus) than in NSW (postcodes 2000 +)
Component filtering is correct. Use: &components=country:AU|postal_code:2340 in the url