# GoogleMaps API with component filter doesn't return same results when i set the country filter

Tags: google-maps

I need to query google maps to find information about a postal code. I need to know where in the world this postal code can be found. For exemple, if i want information about the **postal code 75001**, i expect to receive at least these results:

- Addison, TX 75001, USA
- 75001 Paris, France

If i query google maps by **specifying the country code**, we can cleary see that the postal code exist in the USA and in France:

- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:75001|country:US&sensor=false will return **Addison, TX 75001, USA**
- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:75001|country:FR&sensor=false will return **75001 Paris, France**

If i query google maps by **omitting the country code**, it only return the USA address:

- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:75001&sensor=false will **only return Addison, TX 75001, USA**

Why it doesn't return the one from France?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it using different postal code like this 272012, and it give me two locations, one from China and one from Singapore.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:272012&sensor=false
```

And if I specified the country like CN or SG it give me only exact answer.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:272012|country:SG&sensor=false
```

So I don't have any idea what is the problem with that postal code.

Try to check this SO question if it can help you.

- [Google Maps API Geocode Postal Code and set Country code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747901/google-maps-api-geocode-postal-code-and-set-country-code?rq=1)
- [Get only country specific result using google geocode api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026856/get-only-country-specific-result-using-google-geocode-api?rq=1)