# Google Geocode API giving Zero Results for a particular pincode

Tags: python, google-maps, http, google-geocoder

for a pincode 121003 google geocode api is not giving results although the same pincode is being found out on google maps. What could be the possible issue here ??

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=121003&key=API_KEY

Comment: Could you share your code?
And do you have an API_KEY that should be passed in the request?

Comment: Yes I do have API_KEY and there is nothing like code in this, was just curious why google geocode api is not returning anything for this pincode.

Comment: Duplicate of [Google Maps API Geocode Postal Code and set Country code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747901/google-maps-api-geocode-postal-code-and-set-country-code)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I add `zipcode:` to that URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=zipcode:121003&key=API_KEY
```

It returns a result in India:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "121003",
               "short_name" : "121003",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Tilpat",
               "short_name" : "Tilpat",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Faridabad",
               "short_name" : "Faridabad",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Haryana",
               "short_name" : "HR",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
```

Comment: Yeah it worked, Thanks @geocodezip. Does it mean to search by pincode we will have to use this signature ?